# Gulp setting incorrect export destination directory

Tags: sass, compass

I am having a weird issue with the gulp sass task outputting to the wrong directory.  It seems to be exporting to the root.

Here is my code, maybe someone can tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
return gulp.src(sassSources)
.pipe(compass({
sass: 'components/sass',
image: outputDir + 'images',
style: sassStyle
})
.on('error', gutil.log))
.pipe(gulp.dest('builds/development/css'))
reload
});
```

Thank you!

David

Comment: Can you provide us with the contents of all variables used in given code?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will show you the whole file.  A couple of things aren't working.  It sometimes doesnt seem to be watching the sass files and then reloading and yes, the copy to the correct destination.  In the terminal window, it always reads "write css/style.css", no matter what path I set the destination:

Comment: Sorry got timed out :)

I hope you can access my git repository where I posted it here:

https://github.com/smartcookiemedia/gulp-script/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Thank you for any help,
David

Comment: Hi, you are using "./path" in one dest pipe and a "path/" in dest vars, have you tried to make all the paths similars using the "./" before path route?